# convert jetty-server GET method to POST method

Tags: java, webserver, jetty, httpserver, java-server

I created a `java` web server using `jetty-server (org.eclipse.jetty version:9.1.0.M0)`. My server code is as follows.

```
package webservice;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;
public class ServerClass {
    public void startServer() throws Exception{
        int port=2000;
        Server server= new Server(port);        
        ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler();
        context.setContextPath("/square");
        context.setResourceBase(".");
        context.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        context.setHandler(new ContentHandler1());
        server.setHandler(context);


        server.start();
    }

    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception{
        ServerClass server= new ServerClass();
        server.startServer();
    }

}
```

And here is the content handler code:

```
package webservice;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

class ContentHandler1 extends AbstractHandler{

    public void handle(String target,Request baseRequest,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException{
        try{
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            baseRequest.setHandled(true);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number"));
            response.getWriter().println(number*number);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When i send `GET` method, it works perfect. ie, `http://localhost:2000/square?number=8` returns output 64. But i need a `POST` method. How can i convert this code to process `POST` request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/square");
context.setAllowNullPathInfo(true);
```

It looks like `POST` requests to `/square` are redirected as `GET` requests to `/square/`.

See also: [POST request becomes GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886865/post-request-becomes-get)